# How to create a test.out file to sue for Unity Ceedling testing framework in IAR compiler

Tags: unit-testing, iar, ceedling

I am trying to implement Unity Ceedling test framework with IAR compiler. but the Ceedling asks for a .out file of the test but IAR produces a project out file only. How to solve this issue or create a out file for the test file with IAR.

In my tools section I give the

```
:test_compiler:
    :executable: IarBuild.exe
    :name: 'IAR test compiler'
    :arguments:
      - path to the project.ewp                
      - '-build'              # Command to perform a build
      - 'Build configuration name '               # The build configuration name
```

// This produces a .out file from this command. tried using IAR commands but showed error while running so removed it.

```
  :test_linker:
    :executable: ilinkarm.exe
    :name: 'IAR test linker'
    :arguments:
      - --vfe  #Very Fast Executable mode.
      - --redirect _Printf=_PrintfFull
      - --redirect _Scanf=_ScanfFull
      - --config "path to generic_cortex.icf"
      - --map "path to project.map"
      # Additional flags can be added here if needed in the future
      # - -o "path to the project.out folder"
        
  :test_fixture:
    :executable: CSpyBat.exe
    :name: 'CSpyBat test runner'
    :arguments:
      - --backend
      - simulator
      - --plugin
      - '"path to armproc.dll"'
      - '"path to jlinkarm.dll"'
      - '"path to armsim2.dll"'
      - --plugin "path to armbat.dll"
```

Error message :
Error[Li005]: no definition for "__iar_program_start" [program entry]
Fatal error[Li010]: no modules to link
Fatal error detected, aborting.
ERROR: Shell command failed.

> Shell executed command:
> 'ilinkarm.exe --vfe --redirect _Printf=_PrintfFull --redirect _Scanf=_ScanfFull --config "generic_cortex.icf" --map "project_name.map"'
> Produced output:
> IAR ELF Linker V8.50.9.278/W32 for ARM
> Copyright 2007-2020 IAR Systems AB.
> And exited with status: [3].

NOTICE: If the linker reports missing symbols, the following may be to blame:

1. Test lacks #include statements corresponding to needed source files.
2. Project search paths do not contain source files corresponding to #include statements in the test.
3. Test does not #include needed mocks.

rake aborted!

C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ceedling:23:in `load' C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ceedling:23:in` '

Caused by:
ShellExecutionException: ShellExecutionException
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ceedling:23:in `load' C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ceedling:23:in` '
Tasks: TOP => build/test/results/test_file.pass => build/test/out/test_file.out
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ERROR: Ceedling Failed

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing :test_compiler: to *iccarm.exe* (adjusting arguments accordingly). IARBuild is the command-line build tool not compiler.

Add the following to your project.yml if not already present:

```
:extension:
  :executable: .out
```

Also here is an example Ceedling configuration using the IAR C/Cpp Compiler for **RX**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77493081/22832892.